# Changing content in XML file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Am trying to manipulate an XML file using Powershell.  XML file is 122KB.  When I use the following script, the XML file is then half the size and the service reading the file blows up, but contents are perfect. I'm thinking this is an encoding issue, but not sure how to get around it.  I tried setting the encoding during the set-content, and while I can get the same file size, the NPS service that reads this file doesn't like it.  Opening the file in Notepad++ shows encoding as UCS-2 LE BOM.

```
$content = get-content 'C:\Windows\System32\ias\ias.xml'
$newcontent = $content -replace $oldthumbprint, $newthumbprint
$newContent | Set-Content 'C:\Windows\System32\ias\ias.xml'
```

I'm a bit out of my element, so not sure how much of the XML file I should include here.  This is the one particular line I'm changing -

```
<Unifi_authentication name="Unifi authentication"><Properties><IP_Filter_Template_Guid xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</IP_Filter_Template_Guid><Opaque_Data xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string"></Opaque_Data><Template_Guid xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Template_Guid><msEAPConfiguration xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="bin.hex">190000000000000000000000000000003800000002000000380000000100000014000000e46b7a3127cf1ae043c5336ee1ba33dfbee819800100000001000000100000001a00000000000000</msEAPConfiguration><msNPAllowDialin xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="boolean">1</msNPAllowDialin><msNPAllowedEapType xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="bin.hex">19000000000000000000000000000000</msNPAllowedEapType><msNPAuthenticationType2 xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="int">5</msNPAuthenticationType2><msNPAuthenticationType2 xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="int">3</msNPAuthenticationType2><msNPAuthenticationType2 xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="int">9</msNPAuthenticationType2><msNPAuthenticationType2 xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="int">4</msNPAuthenticationType2><msNPAuthenticationType2 xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="int">10</msNPAuthenticationType2><msRADIUSFramedProtocol xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="int">1</msRADIUSFramedProtocol><msRADIUSServiceType xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="int">2</msRADIUSServiceType></Properties></Unifi_authentication></Children>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you upload a full sample of `ias.xml` it will help people trying to help you

Comment: "the NPS service that reads this file doesn't like it" - does the service throw any errors? Maybe include those

Comment: No errors really.  Just that the service couldn't start.  

Full file available here; had to pull some sensitive info out, so hopefully I didn't screw it up.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljhz6xj7b4rh3ud/ias.xml?dl=1

Comment: So, for reference, for those downloading the `xml` file, it has an unclosed tag. Error can be fixed with `$xml=(Get-Content .\ias.xml).Replace('</>','</Unifi_AP1>') -as [xml]`

Comment: You need to tell us which element is the one you want to update, what is the value of the element you want to update (in the xml file) as well as what is the new value for said element.

Comment: Sorry for breaking the XML. . .Easiest way for me to tell you what I need to change is to simply search the XML for a3127cf1ae043c5336ee1ba33dfbee81980.  That's going to need to change.  It's always going to be a different value.  I always have the old and new values in powershell variables, so I was just doing a replace of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to replace just a part of the Thumbprint or all the thumbprint, try this code and see if it works:

```
$valueToReplace='a3127cf1ae043c5336ee1ba33dfbee81980'
$newValue='00000000000000000000000000000'

$savePath="C:\path\to\save\xml.xml"

[xml]$xml=(Get-Content "C:\path\to\ias.xml") -replace $valueToReplace,$newValue
$xml.Save($savePath)
```

Comment: File is drastically different in terms of lines merged together and such, but it does appear to be working!  Thanks for your help, appreciate it!